# FILEAPIで任意のディレクトリに画像を保存

Tags: javascript, monaca, cordova, filesystems

MonacaにてFILEAPIを勉強しているのですが、HPにあるドキュメントを見ても実装できない事があります。
https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/file/

こちらのドキュメント内、「既存のバイナリーファイルの保存」を活用して、外部から画像を保存する方法を勉強しているのですが、Library/NoCloud/任意のフォルダ に保存出来ません。
PERSISTENTを使用した場合、root以外保存できないのでしょうか？

Comment: 何をどこまで試されたのかを質問内容に含めるようにしてください。可能であれば試されたコードを提示いただくと問題を共有しやすくなります。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: クローズを要請しているため。質問者が複数アカウントでやり取りしているため。

Comment: 質問時とアカウントが分かれてしまっているようでしたので、モデレーターの方でマージしておきました。これで投稿者向けの機能も使えるはずです / このサイトのクローズは基本的に「内容がサイトに合わない・回答が困難」といった時に雑多な回答を禁止する機能であって、質問の終了とは異なります。一旦取り下げたいということでしたら、この質問は削除してしまってもいいかと思います（質問の下にリンクがあるはずです）。

Answer (score 0):

質問内容からは原因が読み取りにくいのですが、以下のようなコードで実現できます。

```
// cordova.file.dataDirectoryがiOSでのNoCloud(library-nosync)
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,
  function(dirEntry) {
    createFile(dirEntry, "hoge.png", true);
  }
);
```